# Cordova Android App Issue - Lollipop

Tags: android, cordova

We've had a number of our Cordova-based app users on Android 5.0 and above reporting blank screen issues on our app - the error we're receiving is detailed below. We're struggling to debug it, as we can't replicate the problem, despite testing on the same Lollipop versions as our customers, both in the Android Studio emulator, and on devices. The blank screen reportedly occurs after a user clicks a button that then loads a new url, with a transition between the two pages.

Without being able to replicate the issue, I don't have the first idea where to start looking in order to resolve it, which is why I haven't posted a code sample - I don't know what to post.

I'm far from an Android expert, and the error below means very little to me. Can anyone point me in the direction of where I begin fixing this? Even being able to see the problem would be a good start..!

```
    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token 
android.os.BinderProxy@196b9dc is not valid; is your activity running?
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:566)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:272)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:306)
    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:1002)
    at org.apache.cordova.Notification$1.run(Notification.java:181)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

Any assistance would be very gratefully received!

Many thanks,

John.

Comment: Can you post any code relevant to building and showing an AlertDialog?

Comment: You're not doing UI stuff in onCreate() are you?

Comment: Thanks for your response - unfortunately, I wouldn't know which code to post, without uploading the entire source of the app. We can't replicate the problem, so I wouldn't know where to place the AlertDialogue...?

Comment: I don't think we're doing any UI stuff in onCreate. It's probably worth mentioning that the app was built by an external agency; we weren't involved in the build other than the design itself. It does run on the jQuery Mobile framework though, which I understand deals with a lot of the UI.

Comment: OK, I think it may be linked to a change in webview: "For apps targeting the L release, WebView has a new default behavior that reduces memory footprint and increases performance by intelligently choosing the portion of the HTML document that needs to be drawn." This default behaviour can be overwridden by calling enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw () - any ideas where I should place this? The top of index.html...?

Comment: @getnorthern Does your app rely on localstorage for data storage? if so it could be that localStorage is not being persisted in the app, which is the issue with the android system webView in android 5.0, see here [link](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=481380)